# C++, .NET: Will this leak memory?

Tags: .net, c++

I am wondering if this will cause a memory leak in C++.

Let say we have a function in C++ in .NET:

```
 test()
 {
     char buffer[NUMBER_OF_BYTES];
     while(forever)
     {
         for(int i=0;i < NUMBER_OF_BYTES;i++)
         {
            buffer[i] = serial->ReadChar();
         }
         String^ serialData = gcnew String(buffer);
         sendDataOut(serialData);
     }
 }
```

This thing basically just waits for fixed number of serial characters which are placed in a String object to be shipped out for processing.  Will the String object be reused or will a new one be created every time through -- eventually chewing through all the PC's memory?  If someone can give me some insight, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new one will be created every time. It is allocated with the garbage collector though and so will be deleted when it is no longer referenced. I don't think you need to worry about it causing a memory leak - the only way that would happen is if sendDataOut stores the strings permanently in some collection somewhere, which I'd guess is not the case.

Comment: A "leak" is, per definition, a resource you can not reference in any way anymore. Storing it in a collection doesn't really count as a "leak". :) It just lives longer than maybe desired.

Comment: Thanks.  Of course, it is no longer referenced and will be garbage collected.

Comment: Yeah exactly Xeo, that's what I was thinking.